# Mounting volumes from linux container to windows container

Tags: postgresql, docker, windows-container, linux-containers

I have docker on windows running a Windows container but also running Linux container. I'm having a problem mounting volumes from Linux container to Windows container. Given the sample below.

```
services:
    postgres:
        platform: linux
        image: postgres
        restart: unless-stopped
        container_name: pgsql-server
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        volumes: 
            - ./postgres/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
```

How do you do this properly? And yes, I have tried some of the suggestion by changing this to:

- C:\postgres\db:\var\lib\postgresql\data
- C:\postgres\db:C:\var\lib\postgresql\data

But did not work. I'm still getting this error: `Cannot create container for service postgres: invalid volume specification:`.

Answer (score 0):

It [seems](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5842) that this is a common issue on Windows. Maybe some tweaking of the local path (on the left side) of the definition, will bring the desired result.

Instead of using a relative volume on the host machine - you can also use [docker volumes managed by docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-volume-with-docker-compose).

```
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres
        restart: unless-stopped
        container_name: pgsql-server
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        volumes: 
            - postgres_db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        ports:
            - 5432:5432

volumes:
  postgres_db:
```

This *should* work properly on Windows (and Linux).